# Select only reviews that have an image using addFieldToFilter

Tags: product, database, query

I'm currently doing the following query to get the reviews from the review table.

```
$summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', Mage_Review_Model_Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT)
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_pk_value', $_product->getId());
```

It works well and get the reviews however I want to add a new filter.

We have the normal setup but in `review_detail` we have a column called `image`, how can I filter the results to only get results where the image field has a value?

I've tried the following but it returns nothing, I presume it's looking for `image` in the `review` table?

```
$summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', Mage_Review_Model_Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT)
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_pk_value', $_product->getId());
    ->addFieldToFilter('image', 'notnull');
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `->addFieldToFilter('image', 'notnull')`
try this:

```
$summaryData->getSelect()->where('detail.image IS NOT NULL')
```

The image field (like others) are not part pf the main table (`review`).  If you look at the `_initSelect` method in the review collection model you will see that there is a left join with the `review_details` table that has the alias `detail`

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->getSelect()
        ->join(array('detail' => $this->_reviewDetailTable),
            'main_table.review_id = detail.review_id',
            array('detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id'));
    return $this;
}
```

This filter should work, but your result will not contain the `image` column from the details table. If you want that in the result you need to rewrite the method I mentioned above and add the `image` column in the list of columns to be selected when the join is done.

Comment: Could you give an example of the whole query please?

Comment: Sorry I cannot. Just put an `echo $collection->getSelect()` where you use this collection and you will see the query.